# After upgrading, the Owl Carousel settings are missing

Tags: views, 10, upgrading

After updating Drupal 10 all functionalist are working fine except in View owl carousel Format some settings are missing.

Drupal 9 Setting
We have settings like "Items Desktop", "Items Desktop Small", "Items Tablet" and some other settings like this

Drupal 10
they are restricted in that.

Due to settings or any missing functionality, the function breaks. How to fix this issue?

Can you please help with this setting?

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/owlcarousel/issues/3384943

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's an issue in a third-party library hosted on drupal.org or elsewhere.